# whether it is advisable to make changes to standard JS files like bootstrap.js, jquery-1.10.2.js , highcharts.src.js etc. to close sonar observations

Tags: sonarqube

We did source code assessment for the project and observed lot of findings which are related to standard js files like bootstrap.js, jquery-1.10.2.js , highcharts.src.js etc.

Since these are standard JS files, Need your inputs to decide whether it is advisable to make changes to these files for closing the observations.

Comment: Do not change third party stuff

Comment: This is _probably_ not on-topic for this site, but generally you should not change these libraries without a commitment to submitting changes to the upstream projects. Configure Sonar to ignore them.